# Adjective for "character" or "alphabet"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Imagine you want to say something like 'Men' are always inside 'Women'... and you want to add something like, *character-wise* or *alphabetically speaking*. How do you go about it? The problem with *character-wise* is, character is already associated with a person's character.

Comment: Anything but "men's letters are always inside women".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way of saying this is,

> You can't spell *women* without *men*.

One example from popular culture that comes to mind is from [*Simpson Tide*](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/3G04), the [197th episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson_Tide) of *The Simpsons*:

> Marge: A dishonorable discharge.  It's the best we could've hoped for!
>   Homer: You can't spell 'dishonorable' without 'honorable'!

Trying to shoehorn this into an adjective is reinventing the wheel, and getting a square wheel.

Comment: Sort of like, _There is no "I" in "team"._

Comment: @J.R.: exactly; note how the counterpart is not only just as idiomatic, but also just as adjectiveless.

Comment: @J.R. Unless you’re on the same team as Noël is on, of course, which risks Russell’s Paradox.

Comment: Oops, sometimes I wonder whether there's a special formula for asking questions here. The full thing here is someone showed a picture of a boy peeping under the hood of a woman, and added. "Men will always be men, once they come out, they want to go back in". I  had a little difficult time saying that men will always be in women, literally and realistically speaking.

Comment: *In our life there's if / In our beliefs there's lie / In our business there's sin / In our bodies there's die* — [This was my life, Megadeth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FDbjCScRxI)

Answer (score 2):

I think *alphanumeric* can be used, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I was being formal I would say

> 'Men' are always inside 'Women' ... orthographically.

Less formally, I would say

> 'Men' are always inside 'Women' ... spelling-wise.

Comment: -1 Whether orthographically or spelling-wise, it would be ***is*** not ***are*** after 'Men.' See also: my comment @OP. And the formula doesn't work with initial uppercase :) What we are looking for here is an *adjective* not alternative ways of stating the same thing.

Comment: I agree.  But I was answering the question about what should go after the specific given (if technically erroneous) text supplied by the questioner.

Comment: Also, the "are" works better to preserve the punning alternate meaning.